# Lost access to Linux BC partitions after OSX High Sierra Upgrade

Tags: bootcamp, partition, high-sierra

I have recently upgraded my mid 2013 MBP with High Sierra and now my Linux partition that I previously installed via Boot Camp is not available as an OS option when booting while holding the Option key.

Previously it showed as "Windows" (although its Kali). Now it does not show at all.

When inspecting with Disk Utility, I see both partitions along with the OSX partition, but the Linux ones show as "Disabled".

What do I need to do in order to get the boot loader to recognize the Linux OS on startup? Thanks.

Comment: Translated to cars:  I have a bi-fuel car (gasoline/liquefied petroleum gas). I replaced the default LPG storage tank with some custom wood gas carburetor though, which -  after some tinkering - worked for years. I updated the Electronic Engine Management System recently, but the engine won't start with wood gas anymore. - We can't answer this without knowing what "tinkering" might mean. Same here: BootCamp is neither required nor recommended to install Linux. To answer your question we need to know how you installed Kali **with** BootCamp previously.

Comment: Klanomath readies Text-Wall Of Sanctimony.
Klanomath attacks with Text-Wall of Sanctimony! Klanomath misses.